# Insertar lectura de un scanner en input type=text?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, scanner

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion movil donde el form registra informacion pero tengo un campo de escaner que me abre la camara y escanea. El problema es que no me regresa el valor de la lectura , que es la numeracion, no los regresa a ese input de tipo texto. y tengo que poner una tabla para que si pueda devolver el valor. A que se debe ?

Comment: por que usas las etiquetas html5 y javascript? estas programando en java?

Comment: No. Estoy apache cordova

Comment: Me parece que te hace falta un paso intermedio. El resultado del escaneado va a ser seguramente una imagen o un binario, necesitarías algo para pasar de eso a texto. Pero por favor, añade más información (no los regresa al input de tipo de texto, ¿pero regresa algo?) y muestra el código que estás utilizando (¿cómo haces la lectura desde el scanner?) y a ser posible un [mcve]. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y ganar así tu primera medalla).

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo haye jeje !

Comment: function startScan() {
    $('#Escaner').removeAttr('disabled');
    // Inicia el metodo de scan(success, error) del barcodeScanner
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      // Una vez que finaliza el escaneo lee los datos y los muestra en los input
            $('#Escaner').val(result.text);        // Valor del codigo